# Specifying class constraints in value constructors

Tags: haskell, constructor, functional-programming

Is there a way to define a class constraint for a value constructor's parameter?

Something like this:

```
data Point2D = (Num a) => Point a a
```

so that Point can take any arguments as long as they belong to the Num class?

Comment: In general, it's better to put your type constraints where they are actually needed.  It's not the data type, but the methods where the Num type is needed, so it should be declared there.  The type system will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ExistentialQuantification` or `GADTs`, but neither is going to do what you want.  You'll never be able to do arithmetic with two `Point2D` values.  All you know about the contents is that they're *some* instance of Num.  You're telling the compiler to discard all other information about them.  This means you're telling the compiler to discard any information it may have that a particular pair of `Point2D` values contain the same type.  And without that information, you won't be able to do any arithmetic on values from two `Point2D`s together.

This almost certainly isn't what you want.  You can't write a `distance` function, for instance.  What possible use could you have for such a limited type?  About all you can do with them is convert their contents to a `String`.

Edit:

I think I see what you're trying to do.  You just want to ensure that everything in a Point2D is a number.  I don't think you actually want type erasure.

In that case, I'd go with the GADT version, with one really important change:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Point2D a where
    Point :: (Num a) => a -> a -> Point2D a
```

The end result of this is that you can only use the `Point` constructor with two values of the same instance of Num, but you don't lose what the type was.  Furthermore, thanks to using `GADTs`, pattern-matching on the `Point` constructor recovers the Num context for you, which is basically what you'd expect.

But I think the most important thing here is not throwing away the type of the contents.  Doing so makes the type basically impossible to work with.

Comment: Recovering instance contexts for data members seem to work only when pattern matching on the data type (either with `(Point a b)` or with record field names `Point{ x = a, y = b }`). But is there any way to have this for field access functions? That is, when accessing a `Point` `p` with an expression like `(x p)`.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes,** but you'll have to realize that the meaning of your constraint is different from usual generic types.

Usually, generics like in `type Foo a = (a, a)` mean

> *for all types* `a`, `Foo a` consists of two `a`'s

However, in your example, one needs to phrase that differently:

> *For some type* `a`, `Point2D` consists of two `a`'s

or

> *There is* a type `a` that `Point2D` consists of

Thus, the generic type is not **universal** (for all types...), but **existential** (it exists some type...). Under GHC, we can allow this through the extenstion

```
{-# ExistentialQuantification #-}
```

as described in this [article on the topic](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types). Your code, after all, is

```
data Point2D = forall a . Num a => Point a a
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

This should do what you want:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Point2D a where
    Point :: Num a => a -> a -> Point2D a

p :: Num a => a -> a -> Point2D a
p = Point

sumP :: Point2D a -> Point2D a -> a
sumP (Point a b) (Point c d) = a + b + c + d
```

You can also use existensials, but then you can't do anything with the data after pattern matching on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Point2D where
    Point :: (Num a) => a -> a -> Point2D
```

This is a [generalised algebraic datatype](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Generalised_algebraic_datatype).