# How to restrict type constructor to returning Ord types?

Tags: haskell, type-kinds

Suppose I have this implementation of a tree:

```
data Tree a children = EmptyTree | Tree a (children (Tree a children))
```

Is it possible to restrict `children` to returning `Ord` types?

Something akin to:

```
data (Ord children *) => Tree a children = EmptyTree | Tree a (children (Tree a children))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specifying class constraints in value constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810274/specifying-class-constraints-in-value-constructors)

Comment: Oops, may have been too fast out of the gate there.  Not sure that is actually a dupe now that I've looked more carefully at the answers.

Comment: @MattFenwick Unfortunately not, I had already looked at that.

Comment: Do you want an `Ord` instance for `children a` for any `a` at all? Or only when `a` itself has an `Ord` instance? Do you only care that `children (Tree a children)` has an `Ord` instance? There are subtle differences between all of those.

Answer (score 11):

I can think of at least two ways:

### 1. GADTs

Eg see [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADTs_for_dummies).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Tree a children where
    Empty :: Tree a children
    Tree :: Ord (children a) => a -> children (Tree a children) -> Tree a children
```

Now you can do:

```
ghci> let t = Tree 1 [Tree 2 [], Empty]
ghci> :t t
t :: Tree Integer []
```

### 2. Smart constructors

You could use a regular data type with smart constructors that have a restricted type signature:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

data Tree a children = Empty | Tree a (children (Tree a children))

empty :: Tree a children
empty = Empty

tree :: Ord (children a) => a -> children (Tree a children) -> Tree a children
tree val rest = Tree val rest
```

and you can now do:

```
ghci> let t = tree 1 [tree 2 [], empty]
ghci> :t t
t :: Tree Integer []
```

but if you try to add a type which isn't orderable:

```
ghci> let t = tree (+1) []
<interactive>:69:9:
    No instance for (Ord (a0 -> a0))
      arising from a use of `tree'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Ord (a0 -> a0))
    In the expression: tree (+ 1) []
    In an equation for `t': t = tree (+ 1) []
```