# Binary Trees Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

So i have this data structure:

```
 class ordering a where

    order :: a-> Int
```

And i want to create a search tree, where every node is a list of elements, specified by their own order number( root is 1, root of left subtree is 2, root of right subtree is 3, and so on..). Every type of data that is inserted in the tree has an "order" number associated with it that only matters for "tree insertion purposes", and if it is equal to 1, it stays in the root, if it is two, it stays on the left side of the tree, and so on..

Here's my attempt at this:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree
        | Node a order a (Tree [a]) (Tree [a]) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

What i've done, makes sense to me, but apparently is wrong, but honestly i have no idea why...

I'm new to Haskell, and i've been struggling to learn the language, so i appreciate any kind of help from you guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specifying class constraints in value constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810274/specifying-class-constraints-in-value-constructors)

Comment: I think the problem is that you're mixing up the meaning of _types_, of `data`, of _type classes_, and of _classes in OO languages_ (which is perfectly usual for beginner Haskellers). Read some [book(s) on Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Books#Textbooks), that's probably going to be the most effective fix to your issue.

Comment: 1) class names must be written with a capital letter. 2) `Ordering` is a busy name in Prelude, try to use another name for class 3) data and class are connected through `instance`

Answer (score 1):

The `ordering` that you have defined is a type class, not a data structure. `order` is an operation, not a type. Putting the `order` operation in the `Tree` data structure makes no sense.

You also haven't shown us any code to actually insert data, so I'm unsure how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I'm trying to write the structure first, so i can make a function to add some data later :)

Comment: @dcarou: it's reasonable to first specify the data types before _implementing_ any function, but at least you should know what the _type signature_ of those functions is going to be.

Comment: You're right! So basically, in order to solve this problem, how can i use the type class "order" atribute in the tree definition ? Because every type of data has a order number associated to it, so it can be inserted in the right position in the tree

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the function actually. Apparently you want this:

```
insert :: Ord key => (key,val) -> Tree key val -> Tree key val
```

since your tree carries values that are to be inserted according to keys, this `Tree` type must enclose both of them:

```
data Ord key => Tree key val = EmptyTree 
                             | Node key val (Tree key val) (Tree key val)
```

now it's easy to implement the `insert` function. Each tree of a type `Tree key val` will be able to carry keys of type `key` and values of type `val`. To accommodate for various concrete value types in one tree you can use a tagged union type for it:

```
data Myval = My_c1 | My_c2 | MyInt Int | MyInts [Int] | MyString String | ...
```

now a tree of type, e.g., `Tree Int Myval` will carry values tagged with Myval constructors, inserted according to the user supplied `Int` keys.

If you mean that every data type has its own key,

```
ordkey :: Myval -> Int
ordkey My_c1 = 1
ordkey My_c2 = 2
ordkey (MyInt _) = 3
....
```

then you won't use `insert` directly, but rather through an intermediary,

```
ordinsert val tree = insert (ordkey val,val) tree
```

This is of course a simple, unsophisticated way to go about it, maybe this is what you meant.

Comment: What i meant was that the code has to be compatible with every data type (int, char, string, etc...). and that every node has to be a list, so different data with the same ord key, is inserted in the same place

Comment: @dcarou ah, that' something different from what I show, but similar. you want `| Node key val (Tree key [val]) (Tree key [val])` and `insert` would cons a new element on top a list that's already there. But then each elem in `[val]` would be of same type...

Comment: Exactly all the elements should be the same type, but the tree should support any type of data. But can you show it, so i can better understand what's really going on ?

Comment: no, to support *any* type of data is too sophisticated for me. There are ways to do it (look for *"printf in Haskell"*).  This is basic simple way, you'd have to add every type you need your tree to hold into the `Myval` union type explicitly, "by hand".

Comment: @dcarou re `| Node key val (Tree key [val]) (Tree key [val])` scratch that, it's wrong; it should be `| Node key [val] (Tree key val) (Tree key val)`.