# Haskell Data Types and type classes

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming

Due to [a former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824774/binary-trees-haskell), I've been studying hard data types and type classes in haskell, and I want to know if a have a certain class and a data type,

For example:

```
class Example a where

function :: a -> Int
```

and

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree
        | Node a (Tree [a]) (Tree [a]) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

How can I use the function in the class example in the data type tree?

I think it has something to do with instances, but is this correct?

```
instance Example where
    function :: a -> Int, and then i define the function here?
```

Can you give me an example?

Comment: You answered your own question, but: be sure to write `Int` if you mean integer numbers, and not `int` the error messages you'll get will be too confusing.

Comment: haha, thank you @Ingo! So basically the class type is only for defining the functions, and then they should be written in instance, is this right ?

Comment: Answer from Radio Yerewan: In principle yes, but a) a type class is not a type, this is important to remember and b) you could write default implmentations of the functions in the class definition.

Comment: `instance Example where function x = 42`. -- with your `Tree a` datatype, the top `Node` would house `a` value, 2nd level nodes would have lists of type `[a]`, 3rd - `[[a]]`, etc. To have lists `[a]` in each node it should be `data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node [a] (Tree a) (Tree a)`

Answer (score 1):

Your instance implementation should look like:

```
instance Example (Tree a) where
  function EmptyTree = ...
  function (Node val left right) = ...
```

Comment: So basically if a want my data to be ordered when entered in the tree by the function defined in the class Example, is it possible ?

Comment: @dcarou Yes, it is, but I guess you're trying to express as a property of the Tree what should most probably be a property of the data in the tree. But maybe I err ....

Comment: @dcarou - I'm not sure what you mean - do you want the values in the tree to be comparable? You can add an `Ord` constraint to the instance for `Tree` i.e. `instance Ord a => Example (Tree a)`

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the other question you asked lately, I think you want something like this:

```
class Order a where
    order :: a -> Int

insert :: Order k => k -> Tree k -> Tree k
insert key tree
    | order key == 0 = ..do work for items of order 0 ...
    | otherwise      = ..do work for items of higher order ...
```